# BCM4311 Wifi Not Working

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, but now my wifi doesn't work. I installed the additional driver which was just the software modem.

I don't know what else to do about it except for installing the updates, but any time I try, it gets stuck configuring `bcmwl-kernel` source.

This is my first experience with Ubuntu and I haven't been working with computers for very long, so please speak in simple terms.

Comment: First,let's identify your wireless card. Please open a terminal and run this command: lspci -nn | grep 0280. The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \. Then edit your question to add those details.

Comment: This is what I got when I ran that command
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 80214e4:4311] (rev 01)

Comment: It was indeed. I had searched for something, but apparently not very well. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bcmwl-kernel-source is incorrect for your device. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your success.